# RingCentral Meetings API - User needs to have [Meetings] Permission

Tags: ringcentral

I'm trying to use RingCentral Meetings API primarily createMeeting using this [guide](https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/meetings/quick-start/python) and [this API Reference](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Meeting-Management/createMeeting), and I'm getting the following error

```
{
  "errorCode":"CMN-408",
  "message":"In order to call this API endpoint, user needs to have [Meetings] permission for requested resource.",
  "errors":[
    {
      "errorCode":"CMN-408",
      "message":"In order to call this API endpoint, user needs to have [Meetings] permission for requested resource.",
      "permissionName":"Meetings"
    }
  ],
  "permissionName":"Meetings"
}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977970/ringcentral-meetings-api-error-user-needs-to-have-meetings-permission-for-r) from a post here StackOverflow stated I need to ensure that Meetings permission is granted on the user's role.

On the production environment, the Meeting permission is on the permissions list UI and is checked, however on the sandbox environment the Meeting permission is not even listed on account roles UI, that is the reason why I am getting the error.

I'm creating a new app since and I want to test the Meeting API on the Sandbox Environment, as it is my only option for testing. Graduating into production would be completely impossible since I need the Meeting API to do so, but then again, it is not on the UI.

I found some useful thread on RingCentral Developer forums such as [this](https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/7925/in-order-to-call-this-api-endpoint-user-needs-to-h-3.html) and [this](https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/1183/cannot-create-meetings-in-developer-sandbox-accoun.html), how ever I'm not able to sign in to the developer forums as the sign in page keeps redirecting me to sign in.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Meetings API is not enabled on Sandbox Environment, you would have to send an email to their support, and have them enable it on your backend. The explanation I was given was to limit and give space for others to use or something close to that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want meeting permission in sandbox and you can find the reference here: https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/7925/in-order-to-call-this-api-endpoint-user-needs-to-h-3.html

Which clearly says:
"**the meeting endpoint is not supported on sandbox.**"

Also in Dev guide [here](https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/meetings/quick-start/node)

"**In order to use this API, developers must have a paid RingCentral account. This API is not available to free developer accounts.**"

You can also check this reference: https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/1183/cannot-create-meetings-in-developer-sandbox-accoun.html

where clearly written: "**sandbox account is not enabled to access meetings feature.
Can you let us know the type of your account.** "